# Issues with Browscap.ini

Tags: php, browser, php-ini, browscap

I recently started to use the `get_browser()` function inside of PHP and I encountered a major issue. I am trying to return the browser that the user is using back to the user but when I run the code:

```
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
print($browser['browser']);
```

It returns 'DefaultBrowser'. I updated my Browscap.ini file and specified the location in my php.ini file but it seemed to change nothing. Any solutions, I am very new to PHP. Thanks

Comment: What browser and OS are you testing on?

Comment: Chrome Version 31.0.1650.63 and IE 11. Windows 8.1

Comment: It looks like the current version (5020 Jul 29 2013) doesn't have those browsers.

Comment: Where can I see the supported browsers?

Comment: I just downloaded the file from http://tempdownloads.browserscap.com/ and used `grep` on it :)

Comment: What is the syntax for grep? I am new

Comment: It's just a text file.  Open it in your favorite text editor (even notepad) and just poke around.  `Ctrl`+`F` :-P

Comment: You can download the CSV and open it in excel: http://tempdownloads.browserscap.com/stream.asp?BrowsCapCSV

Comment: When do the files get updated for the new browsers?

Comment: Whenever they get around to it :-P  There's a beta of a new version here: http://browscap.org/.  That probably has IE 11 in it :)

Comment: Still returns default browser... I don't know if it might be an issue with my configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the browscap.ini file is not updated as often as browsers (which is very very often, these days). 
Fortunately, you can just edit the file yourself and copy-paste the newest browsers that are in there, and then increment the version number. Generally the capabilities will be the same or better, so it shouldn't cause problems.

[EDIT]

The browscap.ini file contains entries like

```
[IE 10.0]
Parent=DefaultProperties
Comment="IE 10.0"
Browser="IE"
Version=10.0
MajorVer=10
MinorVer=0
Beta=true
Win32=true
Frames=true
IFrames=true
Tables=true
Cookies=true
BackgroundSounds=true
JavaScript=true
VBScript=true
JavaApplets=true
ActiveXControls=true
CssVersion=3

[Mozilla/*(*MSIE 10.*Windows NT 6.1*64*Trident/6.0*)*]
Parent=IE 10.0
Platform="Win7"
Platform_Version=6.1
Win32=false
Win64=true
```

A general entry for the version, plus a number of entries for specific platforms.
You can just copy these, change the version from 10 to 11, and then add them to the file.

So those two entries would become

```
[IE 11.0]
Parent=DefaultProperties
Comment="IE 11.0"
Browser="IE"
Version=11.0
MajorVer=11
MinorVer=0
Beta=true
Win32=true
Frames=true
IFrames=true
Tables=true
Cookies=true
BackgroundSounds=true
JavaScript=true
VBScript=true
JavaApplets=true
ActiveXControls=true
CssVersion=3

[Mozilla/*(*MSIE 11.*Windows NT 6.1*64*Trident/6.0*)*]
Parent=IE 11.0
Platform="Win7"
Platform_Version=6.1
Win32=false
Win64=true
```

Comment: Could you post a example of this please?

Comment: I added an example, but as Rocket Hazmat commented on the OP, you can also download a beta version from http://browscap.org/ and it already contains IE 11 (but with the usual caveat that applies to beta anything)

Comment: What would i change to add other browsers like chrome and firefox. I just started PHP so i need a little more in depth answers. I just tested it and it still returns me with default browser. Thanks

Comment: Here is a JSfiddle with my PHP.ini and browscap.ini. The HTML section is the PHP.ini and the javascript section is the browscap.ini.   http://jsfiddle.net/HeyItsProdigy/Pmuag/

Comment: All the versions are headed by a line like `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; IE 11.0` So just find the one with Firefox 24, then copy/paste/update the whole block. However, Chrome 31 and 32 are current version, so it is strange it wouldn't be detected. Can you paste your user-agent string ( `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` in php ), maybe there's something about that that prevents it from being detected.

Comment: `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36`

Comment: Have you tried restarting Apache? After doing that get_browser() recognized your user-agent string on my system.

Comment: yes I have restarted Apache multiple times and nothing changes.

Comment: I suspect the issue is that PHP might not be picking up the browscap file at all. Is the setting in php.ini ( `browscap = "C:\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini"` ) the correct location? (I know, very basic, but best to get the check out of the way. -- also double check whether it's `extra` or `extras` in the path)

Comment: I'm out of ideas for now. Maybe it's worth trying an alternative: https://github.com/garetjax/phpbrowscap (reputably it's faster too)